# WordPress site redirects to another, script tag identified, location unknown

Tags: wordpress, tags, malware

One of my website is redirecting and upon checking I found the Script into several place. Like into the Widgets, sidebars, footer, even pages. I removed the scripts from all of them but still it's redirecting. When I try to see the codes from "View Page Source" then I found the script still exist but I didn't found the location of it. Then I try to Deactivate all plugins to check its fixed or not but but still not fixed. But when I Deactivate the theme (StartKit) and switch to another theme then it's fixed.

So, I deleted the theme file from WordPress and Install it again. After activating the theme its redirecting again.

Now, where can I found the script's location to remove that permanently?

*your text*[This is the Script](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Frk7f.png)

Comment: For better support please add some information about the .htaccess file and type of redirection.